# Why is my discord bot not appearing online?

Tags: discord, bots

I'm trying to create a multifunctional bot for discord. However I've come to a major stand still as I can't figure out what's wrong with my code, it runs without any errors and mostly everything is fine, however it doesn't seem to run an essential part of my code which involves getting my bot online on discord.

I call the function from "main.py" that is supposed to get my bot running (online) through the other python file "bot.py"

this is main.py:

```
> import bot
> 
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     bot.run_flea()
```

this is bot.py:

```
> import discord
> import responses
> 
> async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
>     try:
>         response = responses.response_handle(user_message)
>         await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)
>     except Exception as e:
>         print(e)
> 
> def run_flea():
>     TOKEN = 'my token'
>     client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
> 
>     @client.event  # this is what I suspect is the problem
>     async def on_ready():  # bot gets started, calls "on_ready" function
>         print("Flea is now running")  # this tells us that our bot is up and ready

>         client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `client.run(TOKEN)` is on the wrong level of indentation. Change your `run_flea` method to look like this:

```py
def run_flea():
    TOKEN = 'my token'
    client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
    
    @client.event  # this is what I suspect is the problem
    async def on_ready():  # bot gets started, calls "on_ready" function
        print("Flea is now running")  # this tells us that our bot is up and ready
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot :)